# Error from templating a subclass from a templated base class

Tags: c++, templates, subclass, base-class

I'm trying to template a subclass, which will be specified later, from a templated base class. But got error

```
test.C: In constructor ‘myDeri<U>::myDeri()’:
test.C:30:16: warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x [enabled by default]
test.C:35:5: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘~’ token
```

just from the following

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// Base class
template<typename U>
class myBase  // base class to be derived
{
  public:
    myBase(){}
    ~myBase() {}

};


template<typename U>
class myDeri : public myBase<U> // as i know, this should be Template derived class, Template base class case
{
  public:
    myDeri() : myBase<U> {}
    ~myDeri() {}
};

int main()
{
  return (0);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You're not properly calling the templated base clase's constructor

```
myDeri() : myBase<U> {}
```

should be

```
myDeri() : myBase<U>() {}
```

Comment: Or if the OP enables C++11, it could be `myDeri() : myBase<U>{} {}`

Comment: @Praetorian: True. I still think that's a weird feature of C++11